# Django ImageFieldFile set to <ImageFieldFile: null>. How to change it to blank/empty, like other entries in the table?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, filefield

I have a FileField in a Django Model. Some entries in this FileField are set to `<ImageFieldFile: null>`.
The rest of the Model table are blank or actual images. I need to clean this table so that these erroraneous entries are also changed to blank, as this is not acceptable in my DRF API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the image instance.

```
objs =myclassmodel.objects.all() //just assuming this
for obj in objs:
    obj.image = ""
    obj.save()
```

It will you if understand it right.

Comment: Is saving the image as an empty string equivalent to making it an empty/blank field?